# Use of switch with multiple options cases in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

I would like to get something like this in Matlab:

```
x = round(rand*10);
switch (x)
    case {0:10}
        disp('x between 0 and 10');
    case {11:20}
        disp('x between 11 and 20');
    case {21:100}
        disp('x between 21 and 100');
end
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. Don't enter in any of the cases. Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `{0:10}` is not `{0,1,...,10}`,  but rather `{[0,1,...,10]}`. So it's a single cell containing a vector, and of course `x` never equals that *vector*.

To solve it, use cell arrays with one element per cell. To create them from vectors you can use `mat2cell` (or better yet `num2cell`, as in [@thewaywewalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129281/2586922))

```
x = round(rand*10);
switch (x)
    case mat2cell(0:10,1,ones(1,11))
        disp('x between 0 and 10');
    case mat2cell(11:20,1,ones(1,11))
        disp('x between 11 and 20');
    case mat2cell(21:100,1,ones(1,81))
        disp('x between 21 and 100');
end
```

Or, more easily, use `elseif`s instead of `switch`, and then you can use vectors and `any`:

```
x = round(rand*10);
if any(x==0:10)
    disp('x between 0 and 10');
elseif any(x==11:20)
    disp('x between 11 and 20');
elseif any(x==21:80)
    disp('x between 21 and 100');
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A little simple than Luis Mendo's Answer, just use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to convert your matrix of doubles into a cell array of doubles.

```
x = randi(100);

switch (x)
    case num2cell(0:10)
        disp('x between 0 and 10');
    case num2cell(11:20)
        disp('x between 11 and 20');
    case num2cell(21:100)
        disp('x between 21 and 100');
end
```

Comment: +1 I always forget that `num2cell` automatically picks entries one by one

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner solution is to set switch to true. I use this approach all the time given that the "switch" construction is easier to read than the "if then else" construction.

For example:

```
i = randi(100);
switch true
    case any(i==1:50)
        statement
    case any(i==51:100)
        statement
end
```